# object's stage reference lost when re-instantiated after being removed from memory & displaylist

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm building a game. When you die or win a level you're prompted to continue or return to the main menu. If you chose to go to the main menu you can start a new game. When you start a new game, the game is object is created again & it's children have lost their reference to the stage. I'm not sure why this is happening and I've spent over a week trying to figure out why. Here's some code (and descriptions of the code) from the game that should hopefully provide enough insight as to why the problem may be occurring:

if the "new game" button is clicked on the startMenu the NavigationEvent.START event is dispatched. a LevelEvent.COMPLETE event is dispatched by WeeBeeGame when the level is completed.

```
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {

    public var startMenu:StartMenuGenerator = new StartMenuGenerator();
    public var weeBeeGame:WeeBeeGame;
    public var youWonBox:YouWonBox = new YouWonBox();

    public function DocumentClass() {
        // constructor code
        addChild(startMenu);
        startMenu.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.START, startGameHandler);
    }

    public function startGameHandler(e:NavigationEvent) : void {
        this.removeChild(startMenuBG);
        removeChild(startMenu);

        weeBeeGame = new WeeBeeGame();
        this.addChild(weeBeeGame);

        weeBeeGame.addEventListener(LevelEvent.COMPLETE, levelCompleteHandler);
    }

    public function levelCompleteHandler(e:LevelEvent) : void {

        youWonBox.x = this.stage.stageWidth/2;
        youWonBox.y = this.stage.stageHeight/2;
        addChild(youWonBox);

        youWonBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
    }

    private function mouseClickHandler(e:MouseEvent) : void {
        if(e.target.name === "mainmenubtn"){
            mainmenuHandler();  
        }
    }

    private function continueHandler() : void {
        youWonBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
    }

    private function mainmenuHandler() : void {
        youWonBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
        WeeBeeGame.collisionDOC.removeChildren();
        removeChild(weeBeeGame);
        weeBeeGame = null;

        this.addChild(startMenuBG);
        addChild(startMenu);
        removeChild(youWonBox);
    }
}
```

the code that dispatches a LevelEvent.COMPLETE event is not shown but it dispatches when the level is complete. collisionDOC needs to be static because it's needed in a lot of other classes and holds the display objects needed for a 3rd party pixel-level collision detection.

```
public class WeeBeeGame extends MovieClip {

    public var bee: Bee;
    public var beeHurt:BeeHurt;

    public var spawningDaemon:SpawningDaemon;

    public static var collisionDOC:DisplayObjectContainer;

    public function WeeBeeGame() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function addedToStageHandler(e:Event) : void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

        collisionDOC = new MovieClip();
        addChild(collisionDOC);

        bee = new Bee();
        collisionDOC.addChild(bee);

        beeHurt = new BeeHurt(bee.x, bee.y);
        addChild(beeHurt);
        beeHurt.visible = false;

        spawningDaemon = new SpawningDaemon(currentLevel);

        this.addEventListener(LevelEvent.COMPLETE, levelCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function levelCompleteHandler(e:LevelEvent) : void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }
}
```

the first line to throw a 1009 error (Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference) is the line containing stage.mouseX because the stage reference is null.

```
public class Bee extends MovieClip {

    public function Bee() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
    }

    private function addedToStageHandler(e:Event) : void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        this.x = this.stage.stageWidth / 2;
        this.y = this.stage.stageHeight - this.stage.stageHeight / 9;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event) : void {
        if(stage == null){
            trace('stage is null' + stage.mouseX);
        }
    }
}
```

When the swf is first opened and a new WeeBeeGame is created its children have references to the stage. But when WeeBeeGame and it's children are removed from the display list and memory they lose reference and even if they're re-instantiated their references are still lost. How do I fix this? I'm very confused. Thank you all!!

Comment: how can you trace `stage.mouseX` when `stage` is null? It will always give an error.

Comment: Trace 'Bee added to stage' in the `Bee`'s `addedToStageHandler` and see if the event really happens, if stage really exists at that point and if it happens before the error. I bet on `ENTER_FRAME` event or the `SpawningDaemon`.

Comment: Thanks for replying Andrei. I put the `if(stage=null)` part in there to illustrate that the stage is null after the object is added to the stage, removed from the stage, removed from memory, re-instantiated and then added to the stage again. I traced "bee added to stage" in the `addedToStageHandler` and the trace statement happens both when the object is first added and again after it's removed then added again. could it have something to do with the fact that it's a child of a static var and I'm not clearing it correctly?

Comment: You put the `if(stage=null)` in a enterFrameHandler which is supposed to be called every frame. So having null stage there does not mean stage is null after adding. It just means stage can become null at some point in time - for example when you call `removeChild`. You should do the check not in there, but in 'addedToStageHandler'. If the bee is always added normally, what is the exact problem then? Maybe you use the stage reference in the ENTER_FRAME listener and don't remove it when removing children? Also you use levelCompleteHandler in the WeeBeeGame, but you didn't show it.

Comment: if the `if(stage=null)` isn't there the same error occurs on a different line on the class (which uses the `stage` object). this error seems to come up every frame. the var bee seems to be added normally but for some reason it loses reference to the stage after it's been removed (`removeChild` in `mainMenuHandler` function of the DocumentClass class) then added again `collisionDOC = new MovieClip();
        addChild(collisionDOC);

        bee = new Bee();
        collisionDOC.addChild(bee);`.  the levelCompleteHandler in WeeBeeGame updates score etc to a sharedObj - so it's fairly irrelevant

Comment: I can't write answer because the error is unknown and I also can't ask too many questions in comments. Can you remove all extra parts from the game and leave only needed parts to reproduce the error? If you can send me that working example, I can find the error. By the way, as a workaround, you can add a private `myStage` variable to the Bee class, initialize it `myStage = stage` when added to stage, and use it. It should not go away, and maybe you will see what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENTER_FRAME` handlers continue to execute even when the display object is removed form the stage. So when you `removeChild(weeBeeGame)` those `ENTER_FRAME` handlers are still trying to access `stage.mouseX` each frame. You need to stop the `ENTER_FRAME` handlers.

Probably the easiest fix is to add an `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` handler to remove the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` handlers.

A better fix IMO is to not add any `ENTER_FRAME` handlers from your game objects, but rather expose a public function like `update()` which gets called from a single `ENTER_FRAME` handler in your `WeeBeeGame` when the game is running. Then to stop the game completely you can stop all updates by simply removing that single `ENTER_FRAME` handler. This is a common practice.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I'm going to edit my code to have update functions instead of enterframe handlers and hope for the best! I just edited my post - I forgot to mention that the levelCompleteHandler in WeeBeeGame removes it's class's enterFrameHandler. So I'll aim to make this will be the only enterFrameHandler in the whole game. Will give a correct answer checkmark if this works! Thanks!

Comment: Aaron you rock!! Totally helped!! Opened up a bunch more errors in my code but that's probably my fault after going completely paranoid nuts trying to fix this problem - and ultimately hurting the code in the process. I never new about the update() function standard practice thing. Doing that from now on! T H A N K  Y O U !!!!